# javascript qr code php meta url

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, qr-code

Okay so I'm using this Javascript QR Code generator: https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs

Out of the box you're able to have a string output by including this on a page.

```
    <div id="qrcode"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), 
    "http://example.com");
    </script>
```

I need this to have a prefixed beginning to a url like "https://saucyfreds.com/point-adder/" and then I need to add a WordPress user meta value to the end of this url.

How can I get a WordPress UserMeta value and add it to this url like so?

Comment: can you provide example of desired output

Comment: It's going to be a string generated by a plugin called AutoLogin Links. https://wordpress.org/plugins/autologin-links/ So the output would be "https://saucyfreds.com/point-adder/?autologin_code=wJFdnmmJgbtdHOnydWuEi7CWdlDyBP"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pomaaa's example above in combination with the plugin "Insert PHP" I was able to come up with this solution!

```
    <div id="qrcode"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), 
    "https://saucyfreds.com/point-adder/?autologin_code=[insert_php]                         
    echo get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), pkg_autologin_code, 
    true); [/insert_php]");
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the ID of that user? If so you can do it like this:

```
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), 
"https://saucyfreds.com/point-adder/<?php echo get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);  ?>");
</script>
```

You will have to replace $user_id with the ID of your user and $key with 
the meta_key in the wp_usermeta table you want to display.

If you want to display it for the current user you can use get_current_user_id() like this:

```
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), 
"https://saucyfreds.com/point-adder/<?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $key, true);  ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: This could work but I'd need the id to update to the id of each user who views this qr code? Is that possible?